# Angular Service Worker not working with --base-href in build proccess

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

I want to include the ngsw in my build so that create offline verion of the application. In the build script in the `package.json` I have next:
`"build": "ng build --prod --base-href /test/"`
The generated ngsw.json have the files that are `"/test/index.html"`. 
As I can judge it assumes that I am on the `localhost:3000`, but i use `localhost:3000/test`, so that I got lots of errors. 
How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need replace `"build"` by `ng build --prod --base-href=/test/`